# how do i update an array inside an object which is also inside an array and also in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, rest

[image]

I have a code like
object-array-object-array-object
here I want to change the entire array which is the last array in cycle,
I am using MongoDB,
can you help me to find out how can I do that

```
 Question.updateOne(
      { "comments.id": req.params.commentId },
      {
        $set: {
          "comments.$.likes": updateTheCommentField,
          // 'items.$.value': 'two updated'
        },
      }
    )
      .then((....
```

the above code is not working for me
see the image for better perspective

thank you in advance

Comment: do you HAVE to use the MongoDB framework to do this? This can be easily done with pure javascript

Comment: You need to use `arrayFilters` option with the update method. For example: [Update Array of Sub-documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array).

Comment: can tell me how it can be done with javascript @JohnPan